# Can I take multiple GRE subject tests in the same day?

Tags: gre

Is it possible for a student to sit for more than one GRE subject test in one sitting? For instance, back in high school, I was able to sit for multiple SAT subject tests in one sitting. I, along with other students, had the option of sitting 1, 2 or 3 tests of our choice. Is there a similar policy for the GRE subject tests?

Comment: Are you familiar with GRE subject tests? They're not really similar to the SAT subject tests...in particular, the VAST majority of test-takers will only ever need to take one subject test.

Answer (score 3):

No, you may only take one test during a single session. Unlike the SAT subject tests, you get three hours to do one test, not the other way around.

Source: I've took a GRE subject test last year.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, these tests are set at the same time. So it's impossible to take two tests at the same time.

Comment: ...wouldn't that make it easier to take two tests at the same time than if they were set at different times?

Comment: @Anyon But most of the time we take sub tests to apply for master or PhD program and usually one good score from sub is enough. There is no point taking a lot of trivial tests to demonstrate your skills.

Comment: Right, giving ETS extra money just for the "fun" of taking more tests seems pointless. Yet taking several tests could be useful for someone applying to different kinds of programs, with different requirements. (Of course, even in that (unusual) case I think most would be better off taking them at different times, and focus on getting better scores.)

Comment: Right, all the tests start and finish at the same time on the same day; can't be in two places at once. This comment chain may also have some confusion between the GRE and the GRE subject tests -- the GRE subject tests are not trivial tests that any smart college student can pass in the way that the "regular" GRE is. \

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an actual statement that only one subject test may be taken on a test day. However, in the [FAQs](https://www.ets.org/gre/subject/faq/), there is this question and answer:

> **How much time should I plan to be at the test center?**
>
> Plan to be at the test center up to three-and-a-half hours. Report to
>   the test center no later than 8:30 a.m. If you arrive late, you might
>   not be admitted and your test fee will be forfeited.

That implies that only one subject exam can be taken on a test day.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one testing time per day, so you can't take more than one test in a day (ok, if you flew east across the international date line, you might be able to pull it off).

Theoretically, there are multiple testing times in the same week.  The GRE does offer Monday testing in addition to Saturday testing, though this is supposed to be only for religious and cultural purposes.  (I say 'supposed to be' because somehow my own subject test was scheduled for a Monday, which I realized after not being admitted to the testing center on Saturday.)

Comment: I think you are discussing the regular GRE. The GRE subject test is generally offered only 3 times a year in the US (and, IIRC, only ~1 time a year elsewhere).